# to redirect the print output from python to a label or a tab in qt

Tags: python, qt

to redirect the print output from python to a label or a tab in qt.

I am designing a GUI using QT framework using python code. I want to get the print output into a tab/label/console to the QT creator or designer.

```
        if re.match("(.*)(error)(.*)", line):
            count = count + 1
            file1 = open("Error.txt", "a")
            file1.write(line)
print "error:", count
```

This is the piece of code in python to find the errors in a file and print its count. As the output is being displayed in the terminal when python script is ran, I want the output to be printed in a label in QT designer. I am trying to use settext for label. I am not used to C++ coding, please help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Your question is super generic, please be more specific about what is blocking you or failing.

Comment: To write into console (easiest): #include <QDebug> at top of file and qDebug()<<"error: "<<count; for output. For using lables, build and analyse a demo QDialog application.